# How to deal with an empty object {} in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

The response I sometimes get from the server is a JSON representing an empty object like this {}

I've read [this question/answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826310/object-mapping-an-empty-response-with-restkit) already, which states I should implement the willMapData delegate function and point the *mappableData somewhere else. The thing is I can't figure out what should I assign to *mappableData so that my app won't crash.

I've tried this

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)loader willMapData:(inout id *)mappableData
{
    id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON]; 
    *mappableData = [parser objectFromString:@"{\"unknownObject\":\"\"}" error:nil];
}
```

But nevertheless my app crashes with a rather pissing

```
    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

Can you help me out?

**UPDATE**
Turning on RKDebug messages gives me this in the console:

```
Performing object mapping sourceObject: {
    }
and targetObject: (null)
```

then the code reaches RKObjectMapper.m:

```
if (mappableData) {
        id mappingResult = [self performMappingForObject:mappableData atKeyPath:@"" usingMapping:mappingsForContext];
        foundMappable = YES;
        results = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:mappingResult forKey:@""];
    }
```

but mappingResult over there comes back nil... so the app crashes when it tries to create an NSDictionary with a nil object.

Comment: Where does it crash? It should not crash when you have an empty response.

Comment: I updated the question to show where it crashes. I just found out that Restkit is trying to map the response to an RKErrorMessage ( which is correct, as I get a 404 from the server ). My RKErrorMessage mapping declares a "msg": keyPath... so if I give a @"{\"msg\":\"\"}" to the parser, Restkit doesn't crash. Nevertheless I feel this is not a very nice solution...

Comment: Easy enough to fix, put if(mappingResult) before the results are set

Comment: Sure ! The thing is, this is part of the RestKit module! Perhaps I'll file a bug report or something..

Answer (score 1):

Break up the assignment into two lines.

```
SomeDataType *object =  [parser objectFromString:@"{\"unknownObject\":\"\"}" error:nil];

if(object){
  *mappableData = object;
}else{
  // You've got nil, do something with it
}
```

Now you can check for nil values and take the appropriate action. What that action is depends on the context of the crash.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did not explain myself well enough or I'm missing something, but the thing is as Restkit tries to deserialize the empty object, it crashes. What I don't know is what the context of the crash is or how to prevent the crash! What I'm trying to achieve when I assign the mappableData with [parser objectFromString:@"{\"unknownObject\":\"\"}" error:nil]; is to allow Restkit to fail without crashing...

Comment: Oooh, I see. Might be a bug with RestKit? I can suggest a search and replace on your input string before passing it to RestKit?